# how to connect input tags with form fields in django

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have input tags in an HTML page and I want to connect those with form fields
I have linked forms with a model to save the details in the database. when I am adding signup-form as a parameter in return, the model is displaying its own form and my own form is also displaying. I want the code to connect my Html form with the Django form using the name attribute
login.html

```
<form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="register" class="input-group-register needs-validation" novalidate oninput='up2.setCustomValidity(up2.value != up.value ? "Passwords do not match." : "")'> 
                    <!-- {{ signup_form.as_p }} -->
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    
                    <input type="text" class="input-field" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" name = "first_name" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid first name.</div>
                    <input type="text" class="input-field" id="lastname" name = "last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid last name.</div>
                    <input type="email" class="input-field" id="email" name = "emailid" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid Email Address.</div>
                    <input type="number" class="input-field" id="mobile" name = "number" placeholder="Mobile" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your Mobile Number.</div>
                    <input type="password" class="input-field" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="up" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your password.</div>
                    <input type="password" class="input-field" id="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="up2" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Password doesn't match.</div>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check-box" required> <span> I agree to the Terms & Conditions </span>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">You must agree before submitting.</div>
                    <button type="submit" name = "submit" class="submit-btn" value="checkform1"> SignUp </button>
                </form>
```

views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        register_status = False
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'checkform1':
            return render(request,'first_app/Login.html')
```

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormSl
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'up' : forms.PasswordInput(),
            'up2' : forms.PasswordInput()
        }
```

models.py

```
class FormSl(models.Model):
    # for signup and login
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 32, unique = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 32, unique = True)
    emailid = models.EmailField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
    up = models.CharField(max_length = 32, unique = True)
    up2 = models.CharField(max_length = 32, unique = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Comment: Have you tried this:  `form = SignupForm(request.POST) `and then `if form.is_valid(): `> `form.save()`.

Comment: My question is not that, I am asking how to connect the fields in FormSl (a model class) with input tags in html

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to use a part template for many forms?

Comment: i already have html form i want to link that to model

Comment: What is your `LoginForm`, share also `LoginForm` code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for that. Jquery has [`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method for that. You can move this fields to input's container p element and show in there. Also you can use [help_text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#help-text) field option in django for your forms.